# Yii createCommand vs Criteria

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I've looked everywhere and couldnt find an answer to this puzzling question..

I can do almost everything with Criteria (although it might look "bad" as code) as i can do with createCommand.

So my question is: is there a performance difference or is it just 2 ways to get the same result?

Comment: In the apps that i developed, createCommand is much faster, as it runs under putty for example;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CDbCriteria & createCommand both are ways to create queries in Yii framework. Besides  this some time you need to run mysql queries directly without using such ways.

Its very simple to create complex queries with CDbCriteria and better than createCommand
while you need to run join operations using relations.

But on performance basis createCommand is better than CDbCriteria because CDbCriteria executes some schema level queries to fetch the table columns and executed for each table and each time  time we use CDbCriteria. While createCommand directly executes mysql query, it does not need to run schema level query.

When you start caching queries than on the performance level both are almost similar.

One better functionality about CDbCriteria is its relations queries. So I prefer to use CDbCriteria and Let yii to handle queries in its own ways.

Answer (score 2):

CDbCriteria happens to be a kind of encapsulation for some CDbConnection (DAO in general) functionality. For instance, in ActiveRecord models, most query functions, like find() and similars, use a CDbCriteria object to initialize a CommandBuilder instance. This way, there is an actual difference in performance, as using CDbcriteria actually takes some php execution to generate a db command. I must say, though, that this is non senseless; the [reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar) tells us:

> Although Yii DAO can handle virtually any database-related task, chances are that we would spend 90% of our time in writing some SQL statements which perform the common CRUD (create, read, update and delete) operations. It is also difficult to maintain our code when they are mixed with SQL statements. To solve these problems, we can use Active Record.