# Writing sub queries in yii framework using CDbCriteria

Tags: yii

Hi I am using yii `CDbCriteria` to display values of my table. I had a sub-query in  my MySQL query. But I had no idea how to write a sub-query condition in `$criteria` of yii. Can any one help in doing this

My query is like this

```
select * from (select * from Message order by createdOn desc )as mess group by courseid
```

**Edit**: ***Table Structure***

```
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
courseid int(11) NOT NULL, 
senderid int(11) NOT NULL, 
recipientid int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
message text NOT NULL, 
createdOn timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
status tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0', 
fileName text, 
PRIMARY KEY (id) ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: subselects can be very inefficient, post your table structure I'm sure there may well be a better way to achieve the same results using joins instead.

Comment: `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `courseid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `senderid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `recipientid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `createdOn` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  `fileName` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: so you're selecting from a variable table name? I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. Also, you can edit your question rather than posting in the comments, give you more space to write ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're not using active record for these results if you're grouping? If not you could just run the query itself:

```
$sql = "select * from (select * from Message order by createdOn desc )as mess group by courseid"
$rows = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->text($sql)->execute();
```

But as Stu said, it is very inefficient and it's likely there's a better way to do it.

**Update**
If you do need to get active records from the result then you can always use `ActiveRecord::model()->findBySql()` but your milage may vary

Comment: thanks Paystey but I am looking for how to write it in a  CDbCriteria

Comment: It will be difficult, because like the name suggests it's for building a criteria for querying a database, not so much building a whole command. It's meant as a helper to Active Record and so is not the be all and end all of query builders.

Answer (score 0):

For the query type that you need run, it's better use 'createCommand()'.
Something like this:

```
$results = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('mess.*')
        ->from('(select * from Message order by createdOn desc) as mess')
        ->group('mess.courseid')
        ->queryAll();
    var_dump($results);
```

This post explains well the differences between 'CDbCriteria' and 'createCommand' : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988220/yii-createcommand-vs-criteria)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably not having Yii CDbCriteria display the values of your table in a grid, but rather a Data Provider (like CActiveDataProvider).  You can see there is a CSqlDataProvider. You can also use the CDbCriteria to populate the "where" filter conditions for your sql, and display your table programmatically:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#condition-detail
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#params-detail

```
// your CDbCriteria object:
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->compare('whatever', $this->whatever);


$sql = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->select('*')
    ->from('(select * from Message order by createdOn desc )as mess')
    ->group('courseid')
// .. any other additions to the query.  
// now adding the conditions from the CDbCriteria
    ->andWhere($criteria->conditions, $criteria->params);

    return new CSqlDataProvider($sql, array(
        'keyField'       => 'id',
        'params'         => $sql->params,
     // the rest is up to you...
```

I hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CDbExpression!!!

Example:

```
$criteria->addBetweenCondition(new CDbExpression('(select nombres 
                                    from personas p 
                                    inner join clientes c on c.id_persona = p.id_persona
                                    where c.id_cliente = t.id_cliente)' ), $model->clienteInicial, $model->clienteFinal);
```

No tested :S, but, i am sure that this works!!!
Sorry my English sucks!!